# im passing a variable into html from python through flask, is there a way to display a certain image if the value is less or more than a number?

Tags: python, html, css, logic

What I guess im asking is there a way to do logic in html? If not what would be the best way to do what I want to do?

is there a way to do something like

```
if {{ fkdr }} < 1:
    <img src="image.png" width="250" height="250">
```

Comment: If you're generating that HTML from Flask, yes. If you're trying to do it directly in HTML, no. You'd need something like Javascript or if your HTML is otherwise static, you could use a templating system like Mako or Jinja (which is what Flask uses for its own templating). This also depends on whether or not you're building a site where this value can dynamically change once the page has been loaded or if you just want to do this once at page generation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Flask's [render_template](https://%3Cimg%20src=%22image.png%22%20width=%22250%22%20height=%22250%22%3E) then yes you can use Jinja's [if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if) statement:

```
{% if fkdr < 1 %}
    <img src="image.png" width="250" height="250">
{% else %}
    Do something when there is no fkdr... or delete this else block leaving the endif below
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting a
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
error on
{% if {{ fkdr }} < 1 %}

Comment: @ThatCat It'd just be `{% if fkdr < 1 %}`, not `{{ fkdr }}`